# Analysing time series data with statistics

Tags: statistics, time-series

This is maybe not the 'correct' place to ask this question but for me it's at least the one where I've found the most helpful answers previously. I'm grateful for any redirection though.

My problem is as follows: I have a large dataset that contains forecasted numerical values of a 12 node system. I compare these to the realised values for each node and measure the distance between them. This is an error of sorts.

The data comes as an hourly time series, both negative and positive and spans about 2 years.

The forecasted values are selected from a subset of a pool of data using a sum of square difference function that selects the minimum argument.

I wish to compare results from pools of varying size but I'm a bit lost as to how the 'best' way to do it is.

I would appreciate any recommendations for literature or courses on how one would usually compare methods for time series of similar complexity. Should it be averaged, grouped etc?

So far I have tried the following:

- Compare the absolute value differences of the time series for pools of varying size

The problem with this is that it doesn't take into account the relative size of the error compared to the value of the node at a given point in time. It is important to include this to evaluate the two methods sufficiently.

- Use the following equation to try to take the relative size of the metric into account

100*(abs(x-y)/y)*(1-exp(-abs(x-y)/a))

Where x is the forecast, y is the realised values and a is a number I use to scale the errors (usually around 200) gives me a reasonable value such that small errors < 75 are also measured as small relative to the value of a node and large errors 100+ are also duly scaled.

The problem with this is that I can get infinite values when I have a realised value of zero. I could correct it b relpacing them with a 1 but I'd rather have a metric that could do the same job without this hack.

Thanks

Comment: I think this is more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com since it isn't a specific programming question.